# GET request firing 2 or 3 trying to load 1 page

Tags: express, get, ejs

In my router

```
Router.get('/login', IndexController.login);
```

In my controller

```
exports.login = (req,res,next)=>{
    console.log('login get');
    res.render('main/login',{pageTitle: 'Login'});

};
```

The console logs login get twice, meaning that this is called twice. If I remove the render call then it is logged only once. I have been trying to debug for several days now but still cant seem to figure this one out. When using a curl request from another terminal the log is seen only once as well, but using chrome/firefox/IE yields the double or sometimes triple log call. I don't see this behaviour with POST calls however.
-EJS
-EXPRESS
-Node

**UPDATE**
In chrome dev tools, after inspecting the network tab, I only see 1 GET request being made for the page. It seems that using `res.send()` only fires the log once however using `res.render(....)` goes twice or three times.